# Remove circle/dot next to changed git files in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio

I like the highlighting of changed folders/files in VS Code but the dots bother me for some reason.

[Picture of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt3qr.png)

Is it possible to remove the dots but keep the highlighting? I tried toggling the git decorations setting but this removes both.